# Combining continous bits in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab, sorting, loops

I am trying to combine continuous similar bits in a given array. Example:

Input:

```
a=[0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0];
```

Output:

```
b=[0 1 0 1 0];
```

My input array size is more than 100000, so obviously I don't want to loop through my entire input array. Is there any simpler way? Maybe a recursive divide and rule algo?
FYI, I am running this in MATLAB so any methods which use matrix operations would be awesome

Comment: It can be done in `O(n)` time, yes - but doubt it can be done in `O(log n)`: you need to lookup adjacent elements.

Comment: ya..i was hoping if there was any standard algorithm.

Comment: I think the word you want is "contiguous," not "continuous." And, no, you can't do it without looking at every bit in the general case. If you know that there is some order in the pattern you can potentially skip checking some bits, but you'll still likely look at n/x bytes, where x is some (probably small) constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do much better that looping through the entire array (at least in the worst case).

This solution is of course trivial - you simply loop through - if the current element is different from the last element, add it to the output.

---

You can do *slightly* better than simply looping through with a bit of added complexity.

Consider what happens when we have:

```
...0x1... or ...1x0...
```

Where `x` is either a `0` or a `1`. It doesn't matter what `x` is, the output will still be the same.

So, what we could do, is check every second element. If that element is different from the element 2 positions back, we can simply add that to the output and move on. If it's the same, we need to check the previous element (if the previous element is different, add both the previous and current element to the output, if it's the same, move on).

---

Note that looping the 100000 elements won't take particularly long.

Comment: +1. With a lookup table and a little added logic, you could even do it byte-by-byte rather than bit-by-bit. But at best that would give an 8x speedup (more likely something like 4x, due to added complexity). Still O(n), though.

Answer (score 1):

For the provided example this would work:

```
a(abs(diff(a)) ~= 1) = []
a =

    0     1     0     1     0
```

Though, not sure how it generalizes to other example of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

The following is similar to @Marcin's answer, but it indexes the surviving entries instead of removing the repeated entries:

```
a = a([true logical(diff(a))]);
```

On my computer it's about twice as fast, for a vector of length 100000.